# Disable kernel's printk message log ratelimiting

Tags: kernel

I want to disable the kernel's printk rate-limiting the kernel log messages. Please let me know how to do this, Kernel compile-time configuration / Kernel Command-line option / Sysctl parameter / etc.??

Comment: Why ? Fix the "error" that generate the log-lines that gets rate-limited instead.

Comment: There is no log flooding occurring in the system. I just want to view the kernel messages completely without any suppression by rate-limit feature.